# How to delete table or update column with SQLite.swift ?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I need to re-create my table in my database. Is there anyway to update table's columns or delete table with SQLite.swift ?

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md)? There should be methods for that in any case.

Comment: Yes that one. I checked carefully the documentation but couldn't find anything about deleting or updating table. In the documentation they describe deleting rows and etc.

Comment: In particular there is [this section](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#user-content-dropping-tables) if you search for dropping tables.

Comment: I also just notice that.. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Link to docs](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#user-content-dropping-tables)

Assuming you have your variable for the open database:

```
let db = Database("path/to/db.sqlite3")

// what table to drop and recreate
db.drop(table: yourTable, ifExists: true)
```

And for altering a table

```
db.alter(table: yourTable, add: suffix)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

If you're willing to use [sqlite.swift cocoa pods](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)

Replace the path with the path to your database. This is the project's Documents directory.

Replace the "table" string with the name of your table.

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)

let db = try Connection("\(path.first ?? "")/db.sqlite3")       
let table = Table("table")
            
let drop = table.drop(ifExists: true)
try db.run(drop)
```